# sharedUserId gives shared user incompatible error when running a system application

Tags: android, linux, permissions, android-manifest, root

I have an android app which I need to access all other apps. My device is rooted. Also, I have used `ES File Explorer` to make the the app as a system app by placing it in `/system/app`, I confirmed that it became a system app buy trying to uninstall it, where that was not possible.

But, I need the app to make actions inside other apps, for this I think I need to add android:SharedUserId="android.uid.system" in the manifest file. After adding that and running the app again, I get `shared user incompatible error`.

Is there anyway to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of your app does not match the **"platform"** or **"system"** signature of the device.

To continue with this approach, **you need your app to be signed** with the *platform certificate.*